# PHP Regex/str_replace strange non-match

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

This one is kind of baffling me, I cant seem to figure out why http://www.example.com/a/b/c will return https://example.net//b/c - Best guess is that its conflicting with the first match, but why?

**Code:**

```
 $contents = '
<a href="http://www.example.com/a">Works</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/a/b/c">Doesnt Work</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/x/y/z">Works</a>';


            $regexp = "/<a\s[^>]*href=\"([^\"]*)\"[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/siU";
            if(preg_match_all($regexp, $contents, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
                foreach($matches as $match) {
                    print_r($match);
                    if (!empty($match[1])) { 
                        $urlString = 'https://www.example.net/newlink/';
                        $contents = str_replace($match[1], $urlString, $contents);
                    }
                }
            }

echo $contents;
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => <a href="http://www.example.com/a">Works</a>
    [1] => http://www.example.com/a
    [2] => Works
)
Array
(
    [0] => <a href="http://www.example.com/a/b/c">Doesnt Work</a>
    [1] => http://www.example.com/a/b/c
    [2] => Doesnt Work
)
Array
(
    [0] => <a href="http://www.example.com/x/y/z">Works</a>
    [1] => http://www.example.com/x/y/z
    [2] => Works
)

    <a href="https://www.example.net/newlink/">Works</a>
    <a href="https://www.example.net/newlink//b/c">Doesnt Work</a>
    <a href="https://www.example.net/newlink/">Works</a>
```

https://eval.in/528426

Comment: Do it in a `preg_replace_callback`. The problem is that there are 2 replacements done in `$contents` during the first iteration as there are 2 `http://www.example.com/a` substrings.

Comment: Thank you, will investigate that solution.

Comment: See http://ideone.com/UmJENo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the manual for `str_replace()`

It replaced both occurrences of `http://www.example.com/a` with `https://www.example.net/newlink/`
it is then is unable to find `http://www.example.com/a/b/c`   because it's `https://www.example.net/newlink//b/c`  at this point

**Edit:**  this should work:  `$contents = str_replace('"'.$match[1].'"', '"'.$urlString.'"', $contents);` // include the quotes in the search/replace

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that there are 2 replacements performed in `$contents` during the first iteration as there are 2 `http://www.example.com/a` substrings.

A possible solution is using a `preg_replace_callback` to match the substrings capturing all the parts you need to keep and match only what you need to replace:

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/MzhJ6S):

```
$contents = '<a href="http://www.example.com/a">Works</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/a/b/c">Doesnt Work</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/x/y/z">Works</a>';
$regexp = "/(<a\s[^>]*href=\")[^\"]*(\"[^>]*>.*<\/a>)/siU";
$contents = preg_replace_callback($regexp, function($m) {
  return $m[1] . 'https://www.example.net/newlink/' . $m[2];
}, $contents);
echo $contents;
```

However, I'd rather use a DOM based solution if you are dealing with HTML.
Here is how you can set all links to point to `https://www.example.net/newlink/`:

```
$html = <<<DATA
<a href="http://www.example.com/a">Works</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/a/b/c">Doesnt Work</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/x/y/z">Works</a>
DATA;

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$links = $xpath->query('//a');

foreach($links as $link) { 
   $link->setAttribute('href', 'https://www.example.net/newlink/');
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

See [another demo](http://ideone.com/dms9ZE).

Comment: Thank you! The first solution doesnt complete the <a href wrap it just replaces and returns the URL (seen in your demo) and the second demo appears to be adding an additional closing </a> in addition to the first link not closing correctly. Although i get what you're throwing down, so thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot I removed the capture group from the inner value. So, the `$m[3]` should be replaced with `$m[2]`. That is all the fix necessary for Solution 1. I have just updated the answer. The second demo will work well if you have a normal HTML document, not just a string of tags.